# Voltage problem in printed circuit with switches

Tags: voltage, resistors, switches, board

I've got a simple circuit consisting of a 74157 MUX, whose entries come from switches. These entries have also 10k pull-up resistors, so when the switches are open (default), inputs are at 5V. When pressed, inputs are at 0V.

However, one of the inputs (the one connected to R2 pull-up resistor) is having 0.8V when open instead of the correct value of 5V. I've checked and replaced the resistor but the problem remains.

Any hint of what should I check to find out what's wrong?

**UPDATE:** The problem seemed to be S2 switch pads. I brushed them with solvent, and now, the circuit is working OK. What I'd like to know is why the voltage was 0.8V instead of 0 assuming there was some kind of short in S2. Thanks!

Here's a simplified schematic (only 2 switches represented) of the affected parts:

[image]

And here, a real photograph:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the resistance of the resistor in question?

Comment: Yes, I did. Its resistance is ok. I also replaced it with a new one. @Heller I never said this question was about electronic design.

Comment: Best guess: partial short at S2, or 74157 is dead.

Comment: @Majenko I'll first suppose 74157 is ok as all other inputs are behaving as expected. How should I check S2 short, cutting its track?

Comment: See posted answer below about cleaning it with a toothbrush and solvent

Comment: BUT this forum IS about electronic design. I consider this valuable as it helps people with less experiencesee what goes ito a simple circut likethis BUT ome people are more purist and rightly enough will quickly throw out stuff which id definitely non design related. I think this has overlap - they may not  :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, you are not alone in thinking this has overlap. I find debugging my designs much harder then making them, but that might be caused by the ease at which I make them in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Electronic design section**

Try a lower value of R2 - say 1k or lower. Resistor is pulled down by switch which should/may tolerate higher currents. If this works, summat aglae. If this dinna work, summat aglae.

---

**Other:**

IC may be damage - quite possible

Switch pad may be contaminated with coffee beer blood crud ... - quite possible

Measure pin to ground resistances. Same?

Scrub pads with toothbrush etc with suitable solvent. Be ware of unsuitable solvents :-).

Scratch along spaces between tracks with scriber or equivalent.

Shouldn't be needed, but cut PCB track from S2 - easily repaired again. Better? Different?

---

**If none of the above:**

Go to www.piclist.com
 Join.
 Ask your question with [EE] subject tag.
 Tell me I sent you :-).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found resistance between S2 contacts is quite higher than between S1's and every other switch. Measuring 4A and 4B pin resistance to ground on the IC side gives the same value. But when measuring in the reverse side (the side in the photograph), 4B resistance is much higher.

Comment: May be switch. May be IC. I **assume** you mean lower. try toothbrush or similar cleaning. Try cut track (can then check switch in isolation). ...

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Little mistake when measuring. 4B to S2 GND resistance is lower than 4A to S1 GND.

Comment: What I noticed is that measuring the resistance between all the 10k resistors pins in the board gives a small value (300, 400...) but when measuring R2, I get 10k.

Comment: @grieih, sounds like an IC problem if the other pins are showing a different resistance and the only component other then the resistor is the IC when the switch is off.

Comment: @Kortuk - I'd say IC or switch or track-track bridge, in about that order, which is why I suggested the various things I did. This sot of device can have coffee/coke/stuff get under the rubber and contaminate the contact area. Less likely than IC but possible. Cutting the track to the key is easy and is easily repaired, and proves it without having to plumb out the IC. IC removal is probably required, as you say, but  this is an easy enough pre-check.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, I thought your advice was quite apt. Maybe more details about to accomplish those steps for someone whom is not used to this kind of thing. I thought grieih might want some feedback on the measurement he took.

Comment: @Kortuk - sorry if that came across as a complaint. It wasn't meant to. I aghree with you that ths IC seems the most likely culprit.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, haha. I was just giving Grieih feedback since you had not yet. No worries, it did not.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I finally got to get some solvent, and brushed S2 pads. Now, everything seems to work. What I wonder is why, if there was something shorting S2 contacts, the voltage was **0.8 instead of 0**.

Comment: @grieih - Pullup was 10k plus a high impedance pullup from IC. Whatever "gunk" was on the pad  formed a low resistance but not zero resistance. As the same current (almost) flows through the pullup R and the gunk, tThe voltages are in the ratio of the resistances as V=IR and I is the same.   
 So (5-0.8)/10 k = 0.8/Rgunk or Rgunk =~ 2k. Changing R2 to say 1K as I suggested (just solder scross existing) would have raised voltage to about 3.3V which would have been a large clue.

Comment: @Kortuk - Murphy says option 2 in this case. Murphy is always ornery.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, yessir! Glad it is resolved. On that note, How did you learn my last name? Many a joke was had in school because of it, and my coworkers like to avoid it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thanks! I learnt 2 things: a cheap and easy way to get 2K resistors. And that I need a basic book on electricity so I don't get lost! ;-)